# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined .What should I do when I get such an error and want to keep the currents settings

Tags: javascript, discord.js

An error started popping up for me when I added the "wiezienie.send ("test");" function.
My error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Object.run (C:\Users\User\Desktop\ZukBot-master\src\commands\warn.command.js:63:19)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\ZukBot-master\src\handlers\command.handler.js:126:11)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\User\Desktop\ZukBot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\User\Desktop\ZukBot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)      
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\ZukBot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\ZukBot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\ZukBot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\ZukBot-master\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

My code is:

```
const {
    Permissions: { FLAGS }, Message, Client,
  } = require("discord.js")
  const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
  const client = new Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'REACTION'] });
  
  module.exports = {
    name: "warn",
    description: "Ostrzegasz kogoś",
    args: true,
    usage: "<użytkownik>",
    botPermissions: [FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS],
    userPermissions: [FLAGS.BAN_MEMBERS],
  
    run(msg, args, message) {
        let wiezienie = client.channels.cache.get("761902640552083466")
        msg.delete().catch(O_o=>{});
        const { channel, guild, mentions, author } = msg
    
        const userArg = args[0]
        const reasonArg = [...args].slice(1).join(" ")
    
        const userToKick = mentions.users.first()
    
        if (!userToKick) {
            msg.author.send(`⛔ Wystąpił problem szefie! \`Nie ma takiego gracza na serwerze!\``)
            return
        }
    
        if (userToKick.id === author.id) {
          msg.author.send(`⛔ Wystąpił problem szefie! \`Nie możesz otrzegać siebie byczku!\``)
          return
        }
    
        const memberToKick = guild.members.cache.get(userToKick.id)
    
        if (!memberToKick.kickable) {
          msg.author.send(`⛔ Wystąpił problem szefie! \`Bot nie ma permisji do ostrzeżenia tego użytkownika!\``)
          return
        }
        const wsukces = new MessageEmbed()
        // Set the title of the field
        .setTitle(`⛔ Więzienie`)
        // Set the color of the embed
        .setColor(0xec5454)
        // Set the main content of the embed
        .setDescription("Użytkownik został wtrącony do więzienia na godzinę. Nałożono ostrzeżenie")
    
        memberToKick.roles.add("761901722305298432")
        memberToKick.roles.remove("724576322952888422")
        const ksukces = new MessageEmbed()
        // Set the title of the field
        .setTitle(`⛔ Zostałeś wtrącony do więzienia/ostrzeżony na serwerze \`among us gang\``)
        // Set the color of the embed
        .setColor(0xec5454)
        // Set the main content of the embed
        .setDescription("Zostałeś wtrącony do więzienia, czyli administrator nałożył na twoje konto ostrzeżenie. Posiadasz dostęp do jedynie najważniejszych informacji")
        .addField("Okres:", "Patrząc na twoją aktywną liczbę ostrzeżenień, w więzieniu pozostaniesz jeszcze godzinę", true)
        .setFooter("Zostałeś ostrzeżony!")
  
        memberToKick.send(ksukces)
        channel.send (wsukces)
        wiezienie.send("test");

        setTimeout(function(){ 
          memberToKick.roles.add("724576322952888422")
          memberToKick.roles.remove("761901722305298432")
    
          memberToKick.send("Twoje ostrzeżenie zniknęło. Miej się na baczności!")
       }, 3600000); //time in milliseconds

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to access the `send` property of an undefined variable `wiezienie`.

You should check this line:

```
let wiezienie = client.channels.cache.get("761902640552083466")
```

Most likely it's not returning what you expect it to.

Comment: ok. And are you able to check what I should replace this line with for the code to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I also got an error like this.

Try to change this line

```
let wiezienie = client.channels.cache.get("761902640552083466")
```

into

```
let wiezienie = client.channels.fetch("761902640552083466")
```